# Angular dependency injection sandbox each component separately

Tags: angular

I have an architecture based on component inheritance. The base class provides many useful methods and properties. Some of this functionality requires references to services. If I use DI on the constructor, I'll end up needing to pass many (10+) parameters to the base class on each component I make. To avoid that, I have a service called ServiceBag that has all the services injected into it, and I inject it into all the components; this way, I only need to pass one variable to super(), which is ok.

By default, a singleton is created for this ServiceBag and then passed to all the components. This is ok as long as all the services inside it are also singletons and are only installed once.

I now have a case where a few of them are scoped to the component, so if I only have 1 instance of ServiceBag things are obviously not working.

Bottom line: I want to make Angular create a new instance of ServiceBag for each component instance, on any level of my component tree. I can put it in the providers [ServiceBagService] of each and every component I have, and it works, but it does not make sense to me; there must be a better way to do this. A custom injector, decorator, or something like this will cause it to create a new instance every time.

This method works fine with services that are provided at the root level.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by extending the @Component decorator:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceBagService } from './ServiceBag';

/*
 * The decorator causes the ServiceBag to instanciate every time a new component is created
 * It should be used on all components that inherit from ComponentBase to provide the correct ServiceBag instance to the component
  */

function ComponentEx(args: any = {}): (cls: any) => any
{
    args.providers = [ServiceBagService];
    return Component(args);
}

export default ComponentEx;
```